# Add new item in the Listview is already populate the start of app

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, xamarin

My ListView is populated at the beginning of the application using a ListFragment and BaseAdapter. In Layout i have a button for add new item, but when i add a new item in the ListView items are deleted.

My ListFragment.cs:

```
public class TabItems : ListFragment
{
    AdapterItems _Adaptador;

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Items, null);

        ListView listView = (ListView)view.FindViewById (Android.Resource.Id.ListItems);

        _Adaptador = new AdapterItems(this.Activity,
                                          WebService.ReturnListItems());

        listView.Adapter = _Adaptador;

        return view;
    }

    public override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        Intent activity = new Intent(v.Context, typeof(ChatActivity));

        int value = (int)l.Adapter.GetItem(position);

        bundle.PutInt("value", value);

        activity.PutExtras(bundle);

        StartActivity(activity);
   }
}
```

My Activity.cs

```
List<string> _List = new List<string>();

    ArrayAdapter<string> _Adapter;
    ListView _ListView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TelaChat);

        UtilPop.CreateListViewWithItems(); // populate listview in start

        _ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListItems);

        ImageButton btnAddItem = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.botaoAddItem);

        btnAddItem.Click += btnAddItem_Click;
    }

    void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditText edttxItem = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.ItemName);

        AddItem(edttxMensagem.Text);
    }

    //add new item in listview
     private void AddItem(string itemName)
    {
        _List.Add(itemName);

        _Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,    _List);

        _ListView.Adapter = _Adapter;

        _ListView.DeferNotifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to set a new adapter to your list view in `AddItem`. Try just adding the item to the list, and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your current adapter.

Comment: tnksfor replay, i create a metodh addItem in BaseAdapter: ` public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref _ListOfItems, _ListOfItems.Length + 1);

        _ListOfItems[GetCount() - 1] = item;
            
       this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }`